# How to write an implicit Numeric for a tuple

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, typeclass, implicit, implicit-parameters

I have a scenario where I would like to call sum on a sequence of (Double, Double) tuples.
Ideally I would like to do something like the following:

```
implicit def toTupleNumeric[T](num: Numeric[T]) = new Numeric[(T, T)] {
    def plus(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): (T, T) = (num.plus(x._1, y._1), num.plus(x._2, y._2))
    def minus(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): (T, T) = (num.minus(x._1, y._1), num.minus(x._2, y._2))
    def times(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): (T, T) = (num.times(x._1, y._1), num.times(x._2, y._2))
    def negate(x: (T, T)): (T, T) = (num.negate(x._1), num.negate(x._2))
    def fromInt(x: Int): (T, T) = (num.fromInt(x), num.fromInt(x))
    def toInt(x: (T, T)): Int = num.toInt(x._1) + num.toInt(x._2)
    def toLong(x: (T, T)): Long = num.toLong(x._1) + num.toLong(x._2)
    def toFloat(x: (T, T)): Float = num.toFloat(x._1) + num.toFloat(x._2)
    def toDouble(x: (T, T)): Double = num.toDouble(x._1) + num.toDouble(x._2)
    def compare(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): Int = num.compare(x._1, y._1) match {
        case c if c == 0 => num.compare(x._2, y._2)
        case c => c
    }
}
```

But when I call sum:

```
val seq: Seq[(Double, Double)] = ...
val sum = seq.sum
```

I get a compiler error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[(Double,
> Double)]

Is there a way to implement such an implicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to confuse conditional implicit

```
implicit def toTupleNumeric[T](implicit num: Numeric[T]): Numeric[(T, T)] = ...
```

with implicit conversion

```
implicit def toTupleNumeric[T](num: Numeric[T]): Numeric[(T, T)] = ...
```

With the former you're specifying that the data type `(T, T)` (aka `scala.Tuple2[T, T]`) is an instance of the type class `Numeric` provided that `T` is an instance of the type class. This means that if there is an implicit of the type `Numeric[T]` then there is an implicit of the type `Numeric[(T, T)]`. In Scala 3 the type of this conditional implicit is `Numeric[T] ?=> Numeric[(T, T)]` (aka `ContextFunction1[Numeric[T], Numeric[(T, T)]]`).

With the latter you're specifying that the data type `Numeric[T]` can be used where the data type `Numeric[(T, T)]` is expected and this function `Numeric[T] => Numeric[(T, T)]` (aka `Function1[Numeric[T], Numeric[(T, T)]]`) should be used for such transformation automatically.

I guess you meant the former. So add `implicit` to the parameter `(num: Numeric[T])` making it an implicit parameter `(implicit num: Numeric[T])`. Your code will compile then.

You can refresh your understanding implicits in Scala:

[Understanding implicit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala)

[What are type classes in Scala useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for)

[Implicit conversion vs. type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524878/implicit-conversion-vs-type-class)

[How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala)

[Why are implicit conversion deprecated in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158639/why-are-implicit-conversion-deprecated-in-scala)

[Can someone explain me implicit conversions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861501/can-someone-explain-me-implicit-conversions-in-scala)

[Scala - Implicit conversion to implicit argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701451/scala-implicit-conversion-to-implicit-argument)

[Implicit conversion with implicit parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326880/implicit-conversion-with-implicit-parameter)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-contextual-abstractions-intro.html ...

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/index.html ...

You can also rewrite your definition using a context bound (`: Numeric`), importing implicits, extension methods aka type-class syntax (`.toInt`, `.+(...)`), and type-class materializer (`Numeric.apply[T]`)

```
import Numeric.Implicits._

implicit def toTupleNumeric[T: Numeric]: Numeric[(T, T)] =
  new Numeric[(T, T)] {
    override def plus(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): (T, T) = (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)
    override def minus(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): (T, T) = (x._1 - y._1, x._2 - y._2)
    override def times(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): (T, T) = (x._1 * y._1, x._2 * y._2)
    override def negate(x: (T, T)): (T, T) = (-x._1, -x._2)
    override def fromInt(x: Int): (T, T) = (Numeric[T].fromInt(x), Numeric[T].fromInt(x))
    override def toInt(x: (T, T)): Int = x._1.toInt + x._2.toInt
    override def toLong(x: (T, T)): Long = x._1.toLong + x._2.toLong
    override def toFloat(x: (T, T)): Float = x._1.toFloat + x._2.toFloat
    override def toDouble(x: (T, T)): Double = x._1.toDouble + x._2.toDouble
    override def compare(x: (T, T), y: (T, T)): Int = Numeric[T].compare(x._1, y._1) match {
      case c if c == 0 => Numeric[T].compare(x._2, y._2)
      case c => c
    }
    override def parseString(str: String): Option[(T, T)] = ???
  }
```

[What is a "context bound" in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala)